# Design a CNN from scratch

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tflearn

So currently I am working on a system the require a CNN
But iam still new at this field, so I learned tflearn and I know how to use it, but now iam confused on how many layers of convolution layer do I need and what is the size of the filter of it
I have 28 * 28 image set as input and I want to get 24 output classes so basically all I need is to know the convolution layer pool layer and full connected layer
Any journal or formula could help

Comment: There isn't a formula or anything that provides a perfect solution. It's more like an iterative trial and error approach. Try to plot your validation vs. training score, add layers if you do not face over-fitting and remove layers (or add dropout layers or a penalty) if you do. Regarding the choice of filter size - 3x3 or 5x5 should work out fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to invent something new in most cases, so I advice you to simply choose one of [well-known CNN architectures](https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-10-cnn-architectures-95d78ace614d). Just ajdust parameters and size of whole network for your particular case **if it doesn't fit out of the box**.